# Switching menu between Panel and classic horizontal layout

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

what I would like is to make my site menu switching between panel and classic horizontal menu.My goal is to change the site menu depending on the screen size (desktop/mobile)... but it is another story!

I have the following *working* solution (http://jsfiddle.net/998HD/2/):

**HTML**

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <a href="#0" id="lnkpnl">Panel</a>
    </div>
    <div id="pnl" data-role="panel" data-display="overlay">
        <ul data-role="listview">
            <li>One</li>
            <li>Two</li>
            <li>Three</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">Lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.menu.ui-panel {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 0
}
.menu.ui-panel .ui-li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0
}
```

**JS**

```
$('#lnkpnl').click(function() {
    var menu = 1; // 0 = panel, 1 = horizontal
    if (menu) $('#pnl').addClass('menu').insertAfter('.ui-header');
    $('#pnl').panel('open')    
})
```

JQuery Mobile moves #pnl panel after the header and content and this prevents me from simply apply:

```
.menu.ui-panel {
    position: static
    /*... other props ...*/
}
```

and avoid line 1 and 2 in javascript code.

So, I ask you. Is my solution the best? Is there a pure css solution?

Many thanks.

Comment: you want to convert panel into a menu and vice versa using CSS only?

Comment: @Omar, exactly what I would. jQuery surprisingly move the panel div after the content and this makes more difficult (impossible?) use only css.

Answer (score 0):

You are right on point. There is a way to do this with transition CSS. I included a Fiddle to show you, but it is jquery assisted. Then again, this is a very light JS call so it shouldn't toruble your application. Then again, neither is yours. So you are good either way.

```
-webkit-transition:all 1.0s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition:all 1.0s ease-in-out;
-o-transition:all 1.0s ease-in-out;
transition:all 1.0s ease-in-out;
```

Hope it helps 
[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/XGTRE/)

Comment: can explain the relation between your answer and question?

Comment: Using transition to do what his jQuery is doing...thats what he asked for. A way to use CSS to do the slide effect

Comment: The OP is using [panel](http://api.jquerymobile.com/1.3/panel/) and the panel is animated using CSS transition.

Comment: Im aware. He's not looking for an answer. His solution works. He's looking for other ways to achieve this